# Echo not working properly inside IF ELSE structure

Tags: file, batch-file, if-statement, echo

I have had plenty of problems when moving lines inside `IF`/`ELSE` structure. Code below does not print
`echo %VALUE1%;%VALUE2:~0,2%;%VALUE3%;%VALUE4%;%VALUE5%`
to file. Instead of that values are printed to console and last character is dropped. What is the problem?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET ENABLED_X=1
SET FILE=test.txt

SET VALUE1=23,5
SET VALUE2=34,1
SET VALUE3=0,45
SET VALUE4=3,33
SET VALUE5=3,5

IF /I %ENABLED_X%==0 (
    echo %VALUE1%;%VALUE2%;%VALUE3%;%VALUE4%>>%FILE%
    echo NOT ENABLED
) ELSE (
    echo %VALUE1%;%VALUE2:~0,2%;%VALUE3%;%VALUE4%;%VALUE5%>>%FILE%
    echo %VALUE1%;%VALUE2:~0,2%;%VALUE3%;%VALUE4%;%VALUE5%  
    echo ENABLED
)
```

Comment: Closely related: [cmd, write and read from txt](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40288548)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part `5>>test.txt` will be interpreted as redirection. Normally it's used as `1>>file` or `2>>file` to redirect standard output and error output, respectively.

Use

```
>>%FILE% echo %VALUE1%;%VALUE2:~0,2%;%VALUE3%;%VALUE4%;%VALUE5%
```

instead. Doing the redirection at the beginning of the line will never let it interfere with something else.

Note: without quotes, `%FILE%` is ok. You might run into trouble when using spaces in the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Just place a single space before both of your `>>`
or
`(echo %VALUE…)>>%FILE%`